# sftp atomic move from Solaris

Tags: sftp, solaris

I've got an application that is watching file move atomically to a specific directory.

When doing a sftp from a RedHat linux server, uploading a file to a tmp dir, them moving it with the "rename" sftp to the final dir, my application well sees the new file.

On the same server, but when uploading via sftp from a Solaris server with the same process (upload to tmp dir then "rename" the name to final dir), my application does not see the file. It seems that Solaris sftp client "rename" command does not do an atomic move.

Is it well the case? Is there a way I can do an atomic move from Solaris via sftp?

Best regards,
Raoul

Answer (score 0):

[`rename()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/rename.html) is always atomic on both Linux and Solaris - but `rename()` always fails when the `rename()` is done across file systems.

For an [s]ftp `rename` command to be an atomic operation on both Linux and Solaris server and not a file copy, the old and new file names must be on the same filesystem so the `rename()` system call can succeed.

Assuming your "tmp dir" on the Solaris system is actually `/tmp`, that will be on a separate file system.  Whatever your "tmp dir" is on the Linux either happens to be on the same filesystem as the final directory, or you're just not noticing any lack of atomicity in the sftp `rename` command.

You need to ensure your "tmp dir" and the final directory are on the same filesystem.

Comment: Thanks Andrew,

My Tmp dir is on the same filesytem of my final dit.

What I don’t understand is in both case, sftp fron RHEL 7 and Solaris, we are doing the same sftp command on same dir, but result is different